# Windows boot and system on separate drives

Tags: windows-7, boot, partitioning, ssd, boot-partition

A while ago I *moved* my windows installation from a HDD (Disk 3) to an SSD (Disk 1), however I've just realised I must have made a mistake or followed an incomplete tutorial because my `Boot` files are on my SSD, but my `system` files are still on my HDD.

How do I go about moving the `System` files (and preferably my Reserved partition) onto my SSD? I don't want to reinstall windows.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Boot your machine using a windows OS install disc, and at the first menu press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> to bring up a `CMD` prompt.

Now find out the partition letter assigned to your SSD. Type: `c:` then `dir` to list the files. You need to change directory to `UserProfile` first if it is hard to identify, example: `c:\users\yourname\documents` then `dir` is a command just to make sure you're on the right storage device.

If you're not, move onto the next letter `d:` and repeat until you find the right one.

Once you are on the correct drive type:
`bootrec.exe /rebuildbcd`.

This should rebuild the system partition, then reboot the machine and boot from that SSD.